# Sharing a site on a domain

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I set up a SharePoint Foundation server on a domain.  When I try to access the central admin site, it won't allow me to since the local Administrator account is not on the domain.

When I try to access it using my domain name, it hasn't been shared with me.  When I try to share it, I can't access the share page because the local account is not on the domain.

How can I get around this?

Comment: how you install the SPF on the server? with domain account or Local account?

Comment: Unfortunately with the local account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you installed with local account, which is not supported. That's why you have these issue.

Basically, Stand-Alone installation use the local admin account as they meant for development on machine.

I would highly recommend you uninstall it and re install the SPF again with the domain account for smooth operation.